# Planning regio selective protection of functional groups in glycochemisty

Tags: organic-chemistry, carbohydrates, protecting-groups

Lately I was trying to get a thorough understanding of some questions,
I have delved into many research resources such as Scifinder, Google Scholar, and Organic Chemistry Portal.
but I'm not satisfied with the set of tools available, it takes me way too much time to find an answer.
Can scientists here share with me their workflow, it seems to me there is a more efficient way to reach those answers and those reproducible experiments.

In glycochemistry using selective protection is not trivial due to steric effects and reactivity of the hydroxyl and in many cases protection of the saccharide requires multistep protection/deprotection of the hydroxyl. I would like to ask what approach you will take to selectively protect the hydroxyl in the scheme with benzoyl using small number of simple steps. How do you design the synthetic route and how do you find the appropriate process?

[image]

Comment: The primary alcohol likely will exhibit a greater reactivity towards benzyl chloride, thus react faster than/ahead of the secondary alcohols to yield a benzyl ether. Did you consult  *the typical suspects* (regarding examples) in the books by e.g., Kociensky, or the by [Greene](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/book/10.1002/0470053488)?

Comment: One equally could search (with permutation of the configuration of the stereogenic centers) complement the search in a bibliographic database (like SciFinder) by a search in reaction database (like Reaxys [by Elsevier], thanks to Beilstein; or Science of Synthesis [by Thieme], thanks to Houben-Weyl) if there are reports about similar-enough structures like the intended product.

Comment: I am not a specialist in glycochemistry. I think it will be possible to selectively protect the primary alcohol with something like a bulky silyl ether beyond that the selectivity looked difficult.

Comment: I think you might be able to protect C-4 and C-6 hydroxyl groups with an acetal/ketal (please search literature, as I'm not sure of conditions and I may well be wrong anyway) but I'd expect that establishing selectivity between C-2 and C-3 is going to be a lot harder. (I'm *very much* not a specialist either.)

Comment: C2 & C3 are also nicely set up to form an acetal/ketal, but that does not help in distinguishing between them.